# Mturk externalQuestion with jquery.ajax POST: Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, mechanicalturk

I'm using Amazons Mechanical Turk (Mturk) and trying to submit an assignment as complete so that a worker can be shown the next HIT.

I use externalQuestion and my server stores all the data that workers input. After a worker finished they click a submit button which send the following POST:

```
$.ajax({
  url: self.props.userData.turkSubmitTo + '/mturk/externalSubmit',
  data: {assignmentId:self.props.userData.assignmentId},
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(resp) { console.log('good');},
  error: function(resp, err) { console.log('fail'); console.log(resp); console.log(err);}
});
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit?assignmentId=3AMYWKA6YBMSYVY7OGYPJIPCGPK6OK. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://shrouded-plains-8041.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Note that if i post with the dataType 'jsonp' to try to get around this apparent cross-domain issue then the submit works fine, but the externalQuestion iframe does not refresh to the next HIT.

Im not sure why i get this cross domain 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue. Any help please?

Comment: Please do a web  search for that error. It comes up here many times a day. As for using jsonp you can't use `POST` and jsonp since it is a script request not ajax. Short answer is you need to enable CORS on api if possible or use a proxy

Comment: Ok thanks! Yea i did do a fare amount of googling. That makes sense about jsonp, and why it does not work as expected. I do not have access to the  api to enable CORs. I guess it will have to be a proxy then. 
It does seem strange that Amazon's Mturk requires a proxy to do this fairly standard operation (and that strangeness is why I ask this question). Can anyone with Mturk experience comment please?

Answer (score 2):

I got in contact with the helpful folk at Amazon and they replied:

> Hi Ben -
>
> I believe the problem is that your code is attempting to get the
>   user's browser to submit an AJAX request to Amazon. Since the page
>   with this code is being generated by your own app on Heroku, the
>   browser does not allow this by default (making AJAX calls from one
>   domain to another).
>
> The solution is to have the code do a form submit, not an AJAX submit.
>   See documentation for JQuery's form submit here:
>   https://api.jquery.com/submit/.
>
> Let me know if that works for you.
>
> Thanks, Taneem

Here is the submit code now:

```
  <rb.Modal.Footer>
    <form name="mturk_form" method="post" id="mturk_form" action={self.props.userData.submitTo + "/mturk/externalSubmit"}>
      <input type="hidden" value='' name="assignmentId" id={self.props.userData.assignmentId}/>
      <rb.Input type="submit" style={{width:'70%', float: "left"}}/>
      <rb.Button onClick={self.props.closeSubmit}>Cancel</rb.Button>
    </form>
```